# Why does the $n=3$ energy level of quantum mechanical potential wells appear "upside-down"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, normalization

My QM textbook shows figures like this for the infinite and finite potential wells:

[image]

The even solution for the finite well (applying to the bottom and top curves in the figure on the right) is given as

$\phi_{even}(x) = \begin{cases} 
      Ae^{qx} & x< -a \\       
      D\cos(kx) & -a\leq x\leq a \\          
      Ae^{-qx} & x>a 
      \end{cases}$

where $-a$ and $a$ are the box boundaries (with the well centered on zero). The details of the constants $k$ and $q$ are irrelevant to my question.

What I'm wondering is, why is the n=3 curve seemingly upside down in the domain $-a \leq x \leq a$? The top curve in the figure ($n=3$) implies that $D < 0$, but the bottom curve ($n=1$) implies that $D>0$...

And, even if this disagreement were somehow reconciled, you would then end up with the exact same problem in outside the boundaries of the well with a disagreement in the normalization parameter $A$.

I understand that none of this makes any difference to any actual probabilites, since they are found by the density function $|\psi(x)|^2$. But still, this will not do. Are the figures drawn a bit informally, or am I missing some mathematical details?

Comment: Focus on the infinite well. Behold the n=1,3,5,7,9 solutions in the center of the well, x=0.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see the exact same problem there. The even solutions for the infinite well are $\phi_n(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{2a}}\cos\dfrac{n\pi x}{2a}$. The normalization constant here is positive, but that is not what the $n=3$ wavefunction shows.

Comment: Why is an alternating *D* a "problem"? What part of your solution dictated its sign?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No part of the solution dictated the sign. But a number's gotta be positive or negative. I just didn't like the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Different energy levels have different values of $A$ and $D$. In the second even solution, the relative sign is different from the first.

Comment: My book seems to imply that the normalization constants do not change per energy level? In the case of the infinite well, the constant $A$ is explicitly stated to always be $\sqrt{2/2a}$. And even with the infinite well, I see this same issue at the $n=3$ curve

Comment: @jphollowed The situation is different for the infinite well; in that case $A$ happens to be the same for each energy level. However, you can always replace $A$ with $A e^{i\theta}$ and get the same state, so for the third eigenstate, they chose to plot with $A$ negative.

Comment: In the finite well both $A$ and $D$ change. By changing overall signs, you can always get $D$ positive if you want. However, you can't get both $A$ and $D$ always positive, because the values of $A/D$ really are different between the different states.

Comment: so the real answer to my question is what my prof has been reiterating; the overall phase of a state or wavefunction doesn't matter, since that has to bearing on the absolute square, which we use for probabilities. As long as relative phases between states are preserved

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have expressed the wave-function as though the well runs from $[-L/2,L/2]$, but it is often formally solved in a set of coordinates where the well runs from $[0,L]$.

The "natural" expression of the solution depends on how you label the domain. In the latter case all the solutions are sines for the infinite wells (and could reasonably be described as "sine-like" in deep finite wells) so you would expect them to be rising at the left edge.

Comment: But it could be *negative* sine, and that's what I think the nature of the question is.

Comment: Well, yeah. But like the OP I have preferences in terms of how I set things up. He's saying *"if the solution is written in terms of cosine I expect it to be positive at zero when there is no objective reason to make it otherwise"*. That is purely an aesthetic thing, of course, but a surprisingly large fraction of people would make the same choice. What I'm saying here is that there is a different aesthetic that applies if you label the domain differently. And most elementary treatments I see use the $[0,L]$ domain labeling. You can also fix the sign at either end and that forces your hand.

Comment: @dmckee If this is all there is to the answer, then is it right to say that the figure is simply drawn a bit casually? Indeed you are correct that using the domain $[0,L]$ and expressing the solution as sine curves eliminates the issue I raise. My book did use that domain for the infinite well, and switched when they addressed the finite well (for convenience).

However, even when they re-solve the infinite well under this new domain, the solution does not match the figure entirely

Comment: @jphollowed Frankly, I think you are giving your inner perfectionist a little more lead than is a good idea. I certainly know the feeling—mine's pretty pushy—but this isn't worth much of your time. A lop-sided hand drawn sketch is sufficient to point out the interesting feature of the problem and it's solutions, so these are plenty good enough. Sure, call them casual if you wish.

Comment: @dmckee You're right. I understand the physics and the math anyways. Thanks mate